# Message when Android App is closed

Tags: android, android-activity

I am porting an iOS App to Android, and am having a little difficulty with the terminally.
I want the App to sync when starting/coming to the foreground (i.e. the user selects the App) and when the App goes to the background (e.g. when going to the main screen and start using another App.)

Is there an easy way to do that in Android?
I added onResume() and onPause() to my Activities, but this will be triggered when the activity resumes or pauses, not when the App as a whole pauses (and results in a lot of sync each time the user does something).

Update:
The Sync operation is a Service which is called when the App needs to get new/updated information from the server. As such, this needs to be done when the Application is started/resumed by the suer (after inactivity for some time) and it needs to do this when the user actively stops using the Application.

Comment: IMHO, you are not asking the right question. You should be explaining what your "sync" process is, then asking what the right timing should be for such operations.

Comment: I just want to second CommonsWare on this - what do you mean by Sync?  Also if you're casuing UI freezes due to long running operations (which is what I hear in the 2nd part of your question) you may want to clarify that so that we can address it.

Comment: The the added update make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

when an activity goes to background,

`onPause() -> onStop()`

methods will be executed in sequence, if activity is partially visible, only onPause(), if activity is completely invisible by another activity, onStop() method will be executed after onPause().

```
onDestroy()
```

method will be executed if you either called finish() or when there is no enough memory in the system and system destroys it. You can't rely onDestroy() method unless you call finish() method.

It's best to use `onStop()` method to save your data.

Comment: But is there something that works on the level of the 'whole App', so I only trigger an event when the App is completely dismissed, and not when navigating from one activity to another.

Comment: You have 2 options here, either override onStop() for each activity or make a base Activity class and your other activities will extend it. At the end, you'll be sure that your methods will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

nr4bt has a valid point and depending on your required functionality, a good option.

A global approach would be to start a `Service` when your application starts.

- Make this `Service` responsable for your syncing operations with suitable callbacks to your active `Activity`.
- Make this `Service` aware of your alive/paused/stopped `Activity`'s. When the last one is finished -> Do your final sync and kill the `Service`